# JSoup Data Issue

Tags: java, web, jsoup

So i am trying to get some data from a website by using JSoup, and i am not sure how.

This is the code i have been using and it does not work:

```
public static  Document doc;

public static Elements elementPrice;

public void getDocument()
{
    try 
    {

        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730&q=ak47+jaguar+factory-new").get();

        elementPrice = doc.select("market_table_value");

        System.out.println(elementPrice);


    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I am trying to get data from this site: https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730&q=ak47+jaguar+factory-new

And the data/attribute i am trying to get is this: 
                Pris från:
                35,36€

Which is the price of a csgo item in steam.

And now i wonder why this doesen't work.

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1):

`select` uses CSS selectors syntax so if you want to describe elements by its class use `.className` (notice dot at start). So try with

```
elementPrice = doc.select(".market_table_value");
//                         ^--add this dot
```

You can also use `getElementsByClass` method instead of `select` and pass name of class directly, without any CSS like

```
elementPrice = doc.getElementsByClass("market_table_value");
```

Comment: This works, im getting results but they are not accurate, like when i update the website i get different results. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to help you solve this problem because I don't understand what is the problem. You need to explain (1) what values you get (2) what values you expect (3) and why you expect such values.

Comment: I am expecting to get the current price of an item, which updates constantly and im getting different prices.

Comment: How update process looks like? Are you the one who updates this value? Are you able to see updated price on site?

Comment: Yeah you can see it yourself, here's the website: https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730&q=ak47+jaguar+factory-new

Comment: I don't see any changes on it that site even if I reload it. BTW if this site refreshes its content dynamically without actually need from user to reload it manually then it must be done by JavaScript, but Jsoup doesn't have build-in JavaScript engine and can't do it for you. If that is the case then you will need to use different tool like Selenium webdriver.

Comment: OK, now after reloading site I see prices changed but I also am able to see them via Jsoup. So what is the problem?

Comment: The price is always the same for me via JSoup. Don't know why though it just is.

Comment: @sddds I can't reproduce your problem. When I see that refreshed page contains new price and execute your code again I get data like this http://pastebin.com/WeVFm0A4 or http://pastebin.com/XVfuF60k as result of `System.out.println(elementPrice);` so as you see price is different in both results (I get USD as currency probably because of my location but this shouldn't be important)